# Find Last and Second Last value in a column from a range in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I need to calculate the difference of second last value from the last/latest value in a column from a range in Excel.

For Example

```
1305
1309
1405
1506
```

I need to calculate the difference between 1506 and 1405
Again in next month the values may be

```
1305
1309
1405
1506
1603
```

Then I need to auto calculate 1603-1505

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data was in column A, you could use

```
=INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A),0)-INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0)
```

Adjust the A:A from the above to suit your range of data